# Starting Rails app on EC2 with passenger appears to stop immediately with no error mesage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed a Rails app to EC2 with a RDS databse. When I try to start the app with passenger in production mode I get the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-219:~/tubettmedium48$ rbenv sudo passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 80 -d -e production
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /home/ubuntu/tubettmedium48/tmp/pids/passenger.80.pid
Log file: /home/ubuntu/tubettmedium48/log/passenger.80.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: 

Serving in the background as a daemon.
Problems? Check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#troubleshooting
===============================================================================
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-219:~/tubettmedium48$
```

Does anyone know why this happens? It appears to start and then immediately stop by itself. Thanks.

The output of ps aux | grep passenger is:

```
ubuntu     742  0.0  0.0  10464   928 pts/2    S+   11:44   0:00 grep --color=auto passenger
root     31939  0.0  0.0  33812   984 ?        Ss   11:16   0:00 PassengerWebHelper: master process /var/lib/passenger/standalone/4.0.48/webhelper-1.6.0-x86_64-linux/PassengerWebHelper -c /tmp/passenger-standalone.q1dgzu/config -p /tmp/passenger-standalone.q1dgzu/
root     31945  0.0  0.0   8584   420 ?        Ss   11:16   0:00 /var/lib/passenger/standalone/4.0.48/support-x86_64-linux/agents/TempDirToucher /tmp/passenger-standalone.q1dgzu --cleanup --daemonize --pid-file /tmp/passenger-standalone.q1dgzu/temp_dir_toucher.pid --log-file /home/ubuntu/tubettmedium48/log/passenger.80.log
```

passenger.80.log is below:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-219:~/tubettmedium48/log$ tail -f passenger.80.log
App 6792 stdout: 
[ 2014-08-14 15:07:15.9520 6760/7fb9a22f0700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:298 ]: Preloader for /home/ubuntu/tubettmedium48 started on PID 6792, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.6756/generation-0/backends/preloader.6792
App 6822 stdout: 
[ 2014-08-14 15:15:08.3452 7076/7fce04c3d780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'root', 'cleanup_pidfiles' => 'L3RtcC9wYXNzZW5nZXItc3RhbmRhbG9uZS4xOTBuMXZ6L3RlbXBfZGlyX3RvdWNoZXIucGlk', 'default_group' => 'root', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'root', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/tmp/passenger-standalone.190n1vz/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.48', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'prestart_urls' => 'aHR0cDovLzAuMC4wLjA6ODAA', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'false', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.48', 'web_server_pid' => '7075', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '0', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '0' }
[ 2014-08-14 15:15:08.3511 7079/7fbf40b44780 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:649 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.7075/generation-0/request
[ 2014-08-14 15:15:08.3560 7084/7f9e71dc8780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.7075/generation-0/logging
[ 2014-08-14 15:15:08.3562 7076/7fce04c3d780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
App 7123 stdout: 
[ 2014-08-14 15:15:13.6123 7079/7fbf40a4d700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:298 ]: Preloader for /home/ubuntu/tubettmedium48 started on PID 7123, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.7075/generation-0/backends/preloader.7123
App 7139 stdout:
```

Comment: it's run in background.
what is return `ps aux | grep passenger`?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the output of: ps aux | grep passenger.

Comment: so as i see last process (31945) its your run server.
That return browser on http://your_server_ip.com/?

Comment: Hi, I am really sorry but I don't understand your last comment. What should I do? I get "This webpage is not available" when I go to my_server_ip.com.

Comment: I think that your webserver is running. Can you put here also log `/home/ubuntu/tubettmedium48/log/passenger.80.log` and `sudo netstat -ltpn | grep 80` for better understand you problem.

Comment: I have added the output of passenger.80.log above. When I run sudo netstat -ltpn | grep 80 there is no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  vladdruzh stated: passenger was still running, just running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try reprovisioning or recreating the instances when ever really unexplainable things happen with cloud instances when ever possible.

I have had cloud instances just degrade randomly after 4 or 5 years of running, and one of the things that happens is daemon processes just stop without warning or any errors, which included passenger.

Wasted hours banging my head against the wall trying to trace down what was happening. Resized the instance down for unrelated reasons, and everything started working again. Turns out there was something wrong with the cloud server instance, and resizing forced the creation of a new one.

I assume this same type of behavior could happen on a bad deploy of a cloud instance also, though my experience was on rackspace.

Comment: I have only deployed my app in the last few days. How do I re-provision or recreate an instance?

Comment: I think you can just stop the instance completely wait a little bit and reboot it, should do the job, if not try recreating the server from scratch. If you do that, and even if it doesn't work, you at least know it wasn't something wrong with just the instance.

Comment: I am trying another solution now but will update if I try this way, thanks.